Proving the canonical isomorphism between subspace of skew-symmetric tensors and exterior product
I'm trying to use the first isomorphism theorem to prove that there is a canonical isomorphism between $\mathcal{A}^k(V)$ and $\bigwedge^kV$, where $V$ is a vector space (over some field $K$) and by $\mathcal{A}^k(V)$ I mean the subspace of $\bigotimes^kV$ consisting of skew-symmetric tensors.
First I'm defining $\bigwedge^kV$ by
$$
\mathop{\bigwedge{}^k}V := \mathop{\bigotimes{}^k}V/J^k(V)
$$
where I define $J^k(V)\leq \bigotimes^kV$ to be the subspace spanned by all tensor products $\bigotimes_jv_j$ s.t. for at least two different indices $\lambda,\rho$ I have $v_\lambda = v_\rho$.
If I consider the map
$$
\begin{align*}
\pi : \mathop{\bigotimes{}^k}V &\to \mathop{\bigotimes{}^k}V/J^k(V)\\
\tau &\mapsto \tau + J^k(V)
\end{align*}
$$
then I just need to find a suitable $\varphi \in \mathrm{Hom}(\bigotimes^kV,\mathcal{A}^k(V))$ s.t. $\ker(\varphi) = J^k(V)$, and then by the first isomorphism theorem I'll have an induced isomorphism $\psi : \bigotimes^kV/J^k(V) \overset{\sim}{\to} \mathcal{A}^k(V)$ given by $\psi\circ\pi = \varphi$.
As an additional question, in my definition of $J^k(V)$, is it equivalent to my definition to say that $J^k(V)$ is spanned by all tensor products $\bigotimes_jv_j$ s.t. $\{v_j\}_j$ is a linearly dependent collection of vectors? And how would this definition and possible proof of canonical isomorphism hold for modules instead of vector spaces?
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Hint for the first part: consider the alternator / skew-symmetrizer map.

I don't know if it is true in general, but maybe you can try to generalise this argument.
As suggested, one can consider the skew-symmetric map defined by linearity extension as follows
$$ \wedge\colon V\otimes V\to \mathcal A^2(V), \qquad s_1\otimes s_2\mapsto s_1\wedge s_2:=s_1\otimes s_2-s_2\otimes s_1$$
In this case we clearly have $J^2(V)\subset \ker(\wedge)$ but the equality is not still clear. Let us fix a basis $v_1,\dots, v_n$ of $V$ and consider a generic element $\sum a_{ij}(v_i\otimes v_j)\in \ker(\wedge)$. Clearly, we have
$$ \wedge\left(\sum a_{ij}(v_i\otimes v_j)\right)=\sum_{i\neq j}a_{ij}(v_i\otimes v_j-v_j\otimes v_i)=\sum_{i\neq j}(a_{ij}-a_{ji})(v_i\otimes v_j)=0 \implies a_{ij}=a_{ji}$$
since $\{v_i\otimes v_j\}_{i,j}$ is a basis of $V\otimes V$. Now we can then re-write our element as follows:
$$\sum a_{ij}(v_i\otimes v_j)= \sum a_{ii}(v_i\otimes v_i)+\sum_{i\neq j} a_{ij}(v_i\otimes v_j+v_j\otimes v_i)$$
The first summand $\sum a_{ii}(v_i\otimes v_i)$ already belongs to $J^2(V)$. The same holds for the second one, and to prove it is enough to show that $v_i\otimes v_j+v_j\otimes v_i \in J^2(V)$. Now we use the fundamental properties of the tensor product to write these pieces as follows:
$$v_i\otimes v_j+v_j\otimes v_i=v_i\otimes (v_j-v_i)+v_i\otimes v_i+v_j\otimes (v_i-v_j)+v_j\otimes v_j=v_i\otimes v_i+v_j\otimes v_j-(v_j-v_i)\otimes (v_j-v_i)\in J^2(V).$$
This finally prove that $\ker (\wedge)=J^2(V)$ and so that
$$ \mathcal A^2(V)=(V\otimes V)/J^2(V).$$
Note that this proof holds for any field $K$ of any characteristic.
If you want to know my opinion on the trueness for $k>2$, I think that this is still true. If you want we can think on it together :).
